# Complex Use of Template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I come across a piece of code about template:

**unroller.h**

```
template <int It, int End> struct unroller {
    template <typename Action> static void step(const Action &action) {
        action(std::integral_constant<int, It>());
        unroller<It + 1, End>::step(action);
    }
};

template <int End> struct unroller<End, End> {
    template <typename Action> static void step(const Action &) {}
};
```

snippet of the code that show how it is invoked:

```
constexpr int NUM_ROWS = 2;
constexpr int NUM_COLS = 2;
int input_idx = 0;
for (int pass = 0; pass < num_passes; pass++) {
    unroller<0, NUM_ROWS>::step([&input_idx, input_accessor](auto i_idx) {
    constexpr int i = i_idx.value;

        unroller<0, NUM_COLS>::step([&input_idx, input_accessor](auto j_idx) {
        constexpr int j = j_idx.value;

            ProducerToConsumerPipeMatrix::pipe_at<i, j>::write(input_accessor[input_idx++]);
        });
    });
}
```

Question:

1. `template <typename Action> static void step(const Action &action)` is function template?
2. what is `action(std::integral_constant<int,It>());`? I thought action is pass by reference.  However, i don't really understand it.
3. I don't understand the way it invoke `unroller<0, NUM_ROWS>::step([&input_idx, input_accessor](autoi_idx)`.  My understanding is in the angle bracket <> should be data types.  In this case, it pass the value.  Besides, what is ::step? Then, why it can pass 2 argument in the step(...)>

I am new to c++.  Can someone explain in simple way?

Comment: After reading the answers provided, paste your code into [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/) and look at what it spits out.  You will be able to see each template instantiation and it should help clarify any questions you still have.  Or, it may lead you to other questions that should clarify your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to start learning templates from the beginning.

1. Yes. It's a typical function template
2. No, it's passed by value, at least in your example is passed by value.

```cpp
[&input_idx, input_accessor](auto j_idx) {
        constexpr int j = j_idx.value;

            ProducerToConsumerPipeMatrix::pipe_at<i, j>::write(input_accessor[input_idx++]);
        });
```

this lambda is passed into higher-order function `step` as its parameter, it will later receieve a `std::integral_constant<int, It>` prvalue temporary as the parameter of the lambda.

`std::integral_constant<int,It>()` constructs a temporary object of `std::integral_constant<int, It>`, see this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant

3. It's not two arguments, it's lambda capture, see this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

the parameters of a template don't need to be types, see this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to c++. Can someone explain in simple way?

I'm going to try, but this is template meta-programming that usually needs some kind of expertise mixed with functional style (which is another realm of expertise).

> 1. template  static void step(const Action &action) is function template?

Yes, a function in which `Action` is a parameter.

> 2. what is action(std::integral_constant());? I thought action is
>      pass by reference. However, i don't really understand it.

The general idea of `unroller` is to unroll a loop. This to generate automatically a sequence of calls to something like:

```
action(0);
action(1);
action(2);
...
action(NUM_ROWS-1);
```

`action` is then a parameter to any function that is able to get an `int` value.
The function used here is:

```
[&input_idx, input_accessor](auto i_idx) {
    constexpr int i = i_idx.value;
    unroller<0, NUM_COLS>::step([&input_idx, input_accessor](auto j_idx) {
        constexpr int j = j_idx.value;
        ProducerToConsumerPipeMatrix::pipe_at<i,j>::write(input_accessor[input_idx++]);
    }
}
```

which itself uses the unrolling! Looks like it unrolls a computation on 2D matrix elements. Theses functions are called lambdas, anonymous functions is you prefer. Then you are in the realm of functional programming.

> 3. I don't understand the way it invoke `unroller<0, NUM_ROWS>::step([&input_idx, input_accessor](autoi_idx)`. My
>      understanding is in the angle bracket <> should be data types. In this
>      case, it pass the value. Besides, what is ::step? Then, why it can
>      pass 2 argument in the step(...)>

Template parameters can be types but also values of different kind...
`unroller` is a template type that takes two arguments: `<int It, int End>`.
`It` and `End` are typed as `int`s not `class` or `typename` (as it is with `Action`).